# If $T(n)=T({n\over 3})+T({2n\over 3})+n$ then $T(n)=O(n\log n) $. How is the upper bound achieved?

Tags: combinatorics, recursive-algorithms

Trying to show that if $T(n)=T({n\over 3})+T({2n\over 3})+n$ then $T(n)=O(n\log n) $ using a tree, I do know that taking the shortest path gives a lower bound of the number of steps equivalent to $n\log n$. Trying to take the long path, I try to do it the same but I don't quite see how using ${3\over 2}$ as the logarithm base is legitimate or intuitively substantial. It also seems like I am not supposed to do that. I am a little lost here. Do you have a perspective on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By iterating the recursion,
$$ T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{9}\right)+2\cdot T\left(\frac{2n}{9}\right)+T\left(\frac{4n}{9}\right)+2n $$
as well as:
$$ T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{27}\right)+3\cdot T\left(\frac{2n}{27}\right)+3\cdot T\left(\frac{4n}{27}\right)+T\left(\frac{8n}{27}\right)+3n $$
so, by induction:
$$ T(n) = kn+\sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h}T\left(\frac{2^h n}{3^k}\right).$$
If we take $k=\left\lceil \log_{3/2}(n)\right\rceil$ and assume that $T(n)$ is bounded by $C$ for any $n\in [0,1]$, we get:
$$ T(n) \leq n \log_{3/2}(n) + C\sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h} \ll \frac{n\log n}{\log 3-\log 2} + Cn^{\frac{\log 2}{\log 3-\log 2}}\ll n\log n+n^{\sqrt{3}} $$
since $\sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h}=2^k$.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using ${3\over 2}$ as a base for the logarithm? Otherwise I can simply look at division by ${3\over 2}$...

Comment: @Meitar: $\log(n)$ and $\log_{3/2}(n)$ have a constant ratio, so the base of the logarithm does not really matter.

Comment: Can I ask why we have to bound T(n)? Why in $[0,1]$? That would really help me to understand...

Comment: @Meitar: we bound $T(n)$ because we have to show that $T(n)$ is $O(n\log n)$. We use the following technique: iterate the recursion over and over, till every argument of the involved $T$ functions lie in some interval (say $[0,1]$, but that is just an arbitrary choice) over which we have a uniform bound.

Comment: What I don't understand is the notion of $T(m)$ for $0\le m\le 1$. How can we know it is bounded? How is $T(r)$ of a non-integer $r$ interpreted?

Comment: That should be known in advance: your recursion connects $T(n)$ to $T(n/3)$, so if $n$ is not a multiple of three...

Comment: Okay... Got a little confused by the formality of such interval, that all... Thank you.

Comment: I see you replaced $2^k$ with $n^k$. What justified that? The assumption that $n\ge 2$?

Comment: @Meitar: I did not make such replacement. $2^k$ is just the sum of the binomial coefficients on the $k$-th row of the Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I know, but you wrote $C\sum_{h=0}^{k}\binom{k}{h}$ which then became  $Cn^{\frac{\log 2}{\log 3-\log 2}}$ (or smaller than RHS). Is it an identity?